# Widget configuration

Tags: java, android, widget

My application is fitted with widgets. When the user puts a new widget on it's screen, I want it to be configured. So far, everything is fine : my configuration app is correctly launched, and executed with no error. The problem is that the widget doesn't appear on the screen and instead of staying in the home screen with the new widget displayed on it, the screen goes back to the list of the available widgets.

As indicated in the developer's guide, in the configuration `Activity`, I update my widget in the same way I do it in my `AppWidgetProvider`, and it used to work before I add the configuration `Activity`.

I am certainly missing something. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and also providing a result `Intent` with the appwidget ID as an extra? See step 5 here: [Updating the App Widget from the configuration Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration)

Comment: Yes I do, at the end of the 'onCreate' function of my configuration Activity.

Comment: You should set `RESULT_CANCELLED` in `onCreate()` and set `RESULT_OK` whenever the user actually completes configuration.

Comment: In fact, there is no real configuration by the user. I just use the configuration to individualize the widget by adding an unique extra to it (I want each widget to launch the edition of a different document by the same app).

Comment: With setResult(RESULT_OK, result), it is much better than with only setResult(RESULT_OK)!